# Getting react to work on github pages

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, github-pages

I have followed the stepps and even look at multiple tutorials that all say the same thing yet when i run "npm run deploy" i get an error and nothing happens.
This is the error

> quote-machine@0.1.0 deploy A:\Documents\web\freecodecamp\quote-machine
>   gh-pages -d build
>
> events.js:183
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^
>
> Error: spawn git ENOENT
>       at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19)
>       at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:372:16)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:695:11)
>       at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
>       at bootstrap_node.js:609:3 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! quote-machine@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build` npm ERR!
>   Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the quote-machine@0.1.0
>   deploy script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There
>   is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\Marzdor\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-08-03T23_49_53_940Z-debug.log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible you don't have git properly installed. Try running git from the command line and see if that works.

This issue seems very similar to your problem, check it out: 
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3216

Comment: I have git set to only work through git bash would that be causing this?

Comment: That sounds likely

Comment: Now i get error: cannot spawn sh: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork